Roku Timer Not Firing: Observing Method Not Triggered
I am creating a Roku channel. I need to fire a timer and check if device is being verified or not. It can be a complex logic, but you can see my code below. It successfully adding device, and triggers onAddDeviceResult methods. Then startPolling method is running but it doesn't trigger onPoll method so I can't verify the device. How can I solve this problem? Thank you.
sub init()
    m.deviceActivatedLabel = m.top.findNode("deviceActivatedLabel")
    m.qrPoster = m.top.findNode("qrPoster")

    m.deviceSetting = new DeviceSettings()
    m.deviceSetting.initialize()

    m.deviceUUID = m.deviceSetting.getDeviceUUID()
    m.deviceCode = m.deviceSetting.getDeviceCode()

    qrUrl = "url"
    m.qrPoster.uri = qrUrl

    if (m.deviceSetting.readRegistry(m.deviceSetting.deviceActivatedKey) = "true")
        m.deviceActivatedLabel.visible = true
        print "Device already activated!"
        navigateToNextScreen()
    else
        m.deviceActivatedLabel.visible = false
        print "Starting activation process..."
        addDeviceAndStartPolling()
    end if
end sub

sub addDeviceAndStartPolling()
    m.apiTask2 = createObject("roSGNode", "ApiTask2")

    m.apiTask2.SetField("deviceUUID", m.deviceUUID)
    m.apiTask2.SetField("deviceCode", m.deviceCode)

    m.apiTask2.ObserveField("result", "onAddDeviceResult")
    print "Observer registered for result field."

    print "Adding device with UUID: " + m.deviceUUID + " and Code: " + m.deviceCode

    m.apiTask2.control = "RUN"
end sub

sub onAddDeviceResult(event as Object)
    print "Observed change in result field."
    response = event.getData()
    print "Add Device Response: "; response

    if (response = invalid or response.id = invalid)
        print "Failed to add device."
        return
    end if

    m.deviceSetting.setDeviceId(response.id)
    print "Device added successfully. Starting activation loop..."

    startPolling()
end sub

sub startPolling()
    m.attempts = 0
    m.maxAttempts = 10

    m.pollTimer = createObject("roSGNode", "Timer")
    m.pollTimer.duration = 5000
    m.pollTimer.repeat = true
    
    if (m.pollTimer = invalid)
        print "Failed to create the Timer node."
        return
    end if

    m.pollTimer.observeField("fire", "onPoll")
    print "Observer registered for Timer fire event."
    m.top.appendChild(m.pollTimer)

    m.pollTimer.control = "start"
    print "Polling started with a 5-second interval."
end sub

sub onPoll()
    print "Timer fired. Polling now..."

    if (m.attempts >= m.maxAttempts)
        print "Max attempts reached. Stopping polling."
        m.pollTimer.control = "stop"
        return
    end if

    m.attempts = m.attempts + 1
    print "Polling attempt: " + m.attempts.toStr()

    m.apiTask = createObject("roSGNode", "ApiTask")

    m.apiTask.SetField("deviceUUID", m.deviceUUID)
    m.apiTask.SetField("deviceCode", m.deviceCode)

    m.apiTask.ObserveField("result", "onVerifyDeviceResult")
    m.apiTask.control = "RUN"
end sub

sub onVerifyDeviceResult(event as Object)
    response = event.getData()
    print "Verify Device Response: "; response

    if (response <> invalid and response.activated = true)
        print "Device activated successfully!"
        m.deviceSetting.writeRegistry(m.deviceSetting.deviceActivatedKey, "true")
        m.deviceActivatedLabel.visible = true

        m.pollTimer.control = "stop"
        navigateToNextScreen()
    else
        print "Device not activated yet. Retrying..."
    end if
end sub

sub navigateToNextScreen() as void
    print "Navigating to the next screen..."
end sub

I tried adding Timer into xml file. But still it didn't work.

I believe your issue is this line:
m.pollTimer.duration = 5000

The Timer component takes duration in seconds, not milliseconds. (see this docs page).

duration: Specifies the time in seconds before the Timer node fires after the control field value is set to start. To specify time values down to millisecond granularity, use a float type (0.001 equals one millisecond)


Yes thats correct. Thank you Bron! Also, I was looking a way to make navigation between screens in Roku. Do you know any helpful documentation about that? Thank you.

Code should work fine. Problem is in timer duration. The duration 5000 is actually seconds not milliseconds. So your timer will be fired but after 5000 seconds(i.e. after 1 hour 23 minutes and 20 seconds). If you want to fire it after 5 seconds then set the duration to 5 only.

Thank you so much. I got confused and focused other part of the code. But it was obviously there. I couldn't see it, thanks again.
